# The role of sub-multiplicative property (∥AB∥≤∥A∥∥B∥) and ∥I∥≥1 in the definition of 'matrix norm'

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

A normed linear space $(X, \lVert \cdot \lVert)$ can form a metric space induced by the norm and thereby a topological vector space. Thus the analytical concepts can be taken along with $X$. The axiomatic properties in the defintion of $\lVert \cdot \lVert$ is enough to say the topology induced by the same will be compatible (continuity of 'vector addition' map and 'scalar multiplication' map) with the linear structure.

My Doubt: What is the actual role of sub-multiplicative property ($\lVert AB \lVert\leq \lVert A \lVert\lVert B \lVert$) and $\lVert I \lVert \geq 1$ in the definition of 'matrix norm' ? Are they again compatibility conditions?

Comment: The submultiplicative property is useful for proving many kinds of infinite (power) series involving matrices converge, like the exponential series for example.

Comment: Matrices possess a multiplication operation which vectors spaces sometimes do not.  When a vector space has such an operation, and it satisfies the submultiplicative inequality, then it is called a normed algebra.

Comment: @runway44 Why the usual convergence w.r.t norm ($\lVert A_n-A\lVert \to 0$) is not relevant here?

Comment: .. because one has to estimate $\|A^k\|$. With submultiplicativity, one gets $\|A^k\|\le \|A\|^k$.

Comment: @MessiLio I am talking about the usual convergence wrt the norm.